# Iframe with height based on page content height

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

in my Wordpress site I use a plugin that allows me to view external pages in an iframe that changes its height based on the height of the content.
The page I try to load in the iframe is a simple html page that calls a javascript. 
This however prevents the iframe from changing its height.
Can it be solved in any way?
Thanks.

Here is the code of the html page that must be loaded into the iframe:

```html
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.domain-name.com/script-name.php?param1=1&param2=22"></script>
 </body>
```

Comment: I did a test site to show you the behavior. http://test.eyenet.it

Answer (score 0):

give div ID or Call and the CSS

```
height : 100vh ;
```

try this code on load

```
    function resizeIFrameToFitContent( iFrame ) {

    iFrame.width  = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    iFrame.height = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {

    var iFrame = document.getElementById( 'iframe_block' );
    resizeIFrameToFitContent( iFrame );

    // or, to resize all iframes:
    var iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
    for( var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
        resizeIFrameToFitContent( iframes[i] );
    }
} );
```

Comment: see above i change answer

Comment: Hello,
the code you posted where it should be inserted?
on the iframe page or on the script page?
Can you give me a complete example to use the code you posted?
Thank you